# restrict access to Apache virtual host running as reverse proxy

Tags: firewall, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

I'm using Apache 2.4 as a reverse proxy for Jenkins (a web service running locally on port 8080). I'm trying to limit access to this service to an internal network using `Require`. My VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName jenkins.domain.com
    ServerAdmin  ...

    SSLEngine on
    ...

    <Location />
        <RequireAny>
            Require ip 127.0.0.1
            Require ip ::1
            Require ip 10.8.0
        </RequireAny>
    </Location>

    ProxyRequests     Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
    ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:8080/ nocanon
    ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse  /  http://jenkins.domain.com/
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
</VirtualHost>
```

Somehow this makes the service unavailable to everyone, including clients with trusted IPs like 10.8.0.1. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also used Apache to do reverse proxy with `ProxyPass` and didn't encounter the need to declare the `<Proxy>` directives to limit access since `<Location>` was sufficient.

Can you try commenting out the following part:

`<Proxy *>
    Require all granted
</Proxy>`

Comment: I'm still getting a 403 (You don't have permission to access / on this server). You're right though, looks like `<Proxy>` is not required here. Will remove it from the config in my question.

Comment: In the config that I use, the `<Location>` directive was declared after the `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse`.  You might want to try that too.

Comment: Nevermind, the updated config in my answer (without `<Proxy>`) works! My VPN configuration is now the problem here. Thanks.